# URL not working right in anchor tag

Tags: url, anchor

I tried this:

```
<a href="http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=250778518281&ssPageName=ADME:B:SS:US:1123">Test</a>
```

but it stops after the first :S.  Anyone know why?

It will show a link for:

```
S:US:1123">Test
```

I'm confused.  :)

Comment: Works fine for me with Firefox 3.6.8 on Linux. Which browser, version and OS are you seeing this on?

Comment: Actually, I think it's the engine behind it that was the issue.  I was doing it on a brand new site (well, 3 weeks old) editing someone's post and that's what it did.  But when I did it on here, it worked fine.  Same browser, same OS.

Comment: It works for me in FF on Win7 - It is inside some strange tag or badly formed html?

Comment: The syntax of the anchor tag is correct. Maybe there's a mistake somewhere else in your document.

Comment: No, I needed to put `%3A` instead of `:`.  As soon as I changed it, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine for me, but as a general rule, always ensure your query string parameters are URL Encoded, e.g:

http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=250778518281&ssPageName=ADME%3AB%3ASS%3AUS%3A1123